# Calculate interval if value in column changes

Tags: bash, awk

I am not used to code, but for my work I have to do some processing with text-files and I need some help with a problem I encountered.

I have a file with two columns containing some numbers:

```
180.000000   115.944480
180.000000    95.979157 
180.000000    93.583322 
178.593750   122.797168 
178.593750   120.000000 
178.593750   117.279613 
178.593750   102.024699 
178.593750    99.594068
   ...           ...
```

There are several values in the second column associated with one unique value in the first column. Now I want to print for every unique value in column 1 the interval of values in column 2.

Desired output:

```
115.944480 93.583322
122.797168 99.594068
...
```

Obviously I have to store the values and have to print a previous and the recent value of column 2 if the value in column 1 changes. But that is the problem: How can this be realized in bash or awk?

Comment: Please add a description of whatever progress you have made for yourself in either awk or bash. You should make a minimal effort rather than expecting helpful people doing all the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution for your initial condition *"for every unique value in column 1 the interval of values in column 2"* (as you have changed your condition considerably):

```
awk 'NR > 1{ 
         if ($1 == num1) intvl += num2 - $2;
         else { print intvl; intvl = 0 }
    }
    { num1 = $1; num2 = $2 }
    END{ print intvl }' file
```

Sample output:

```
22.3612
23.2031
```

---

Covering the 2nd condition *"to print a previous and the recent value of column 2 if the value in column 1 changes"*:

```
awk '!a[$1]++{ 
         if (first != "") { print first, last; first = last = "" }
         first = $2
     }
     { last = $2 }
     END{ print first, last }' file
```

The output:

```
115.944480 93.583322
122.797168 99.594068
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works very well for my purpose! Some question about the syntax for my understanding:

What does the  `!a[$1]++` and the `!= ""` mean?

Comment: @quadrupoltensor, 1) `!a[$1]++` gives `true` on the 1st occurrence of the  1st field value `$1`. 2) `!=""` means "is not equal to empty string"